# water to hydrogen to water

Tags: thermodynamics, water, hydrogen

I'm trying to find out if there is any loss of water when converting water to hydrogen and then back into water and can't find an answer anywhere I've searched. I understand that the water produced is a gas, vaporized, but I assume it can be contained and cooled back down into water. So, if you hydrogenize a quart of water and then provide the correct proportions of oxygen to turn it back into water in an exothermic reaction do you get a quart of water back? If there is no loss, then, using solar-energy, can a closed-system engine be created?

Answer (score 1):

How far do you need to go in searching  to stumble upon the law of mass and energy conservation ?

Theoretically, there is no loss. Practically, it is question  of design and material science.

There can be losses in incomplete capture of hydrogen or water vapor. There can be leaks and secondary reactions like material oxidation or corrosion, consuming oxygen. Hydrogen  is vulnerable to diffusion through tiniest holes and even into or through some materials, or forming metal hydrides.

But in large extent, losses are negligible.